# Neighbour dispute

Tags: civil-law, common-law, sri-lanka

If any visitor comes to my home, then when they return from my home, my neighbour comes near the fence and starts talking with my visitors.
I feel it as a disturbance for my privacy and for maintaining a good relationship with my visitors. My visitors fall in trouble because of antisocial and misbehaving activities of the neighbour.
One day I told not to do this to the neighbours, but they are continuing that disturbing activity for my visitors. How can deal this to stop?
Place :Sri Lanka

Comment: Are they complaining to your visitors or calling them derogatory names or...?

Comment: Yes they complain at my visitors . Their jealous talks becomes some nonsense complaints at that moment

Answer (score 2):

If all that your neighbor is doing is talking to your visitors, I do not see any plausible legal remedy.

The neighbors aren't trespassing. Talking with a visitor of a neighbor doesn't ordinarily constitute a public nuisance (unless they are using a huge megaphone or something like that not implied by the question). And, since they are talking to your visitors, rather than you, it isn't really your privacy at issue.

Also, unless the visitors are also your children or employees, you really have no authority or right to regulate how third-parties interact with them.

It is possible that some important fact that would lead to a legal remedy has been omitted from the question, but with the limited facts available, I do not see a legal remedy.